# Method ::find not found in Laravel 5.2 / Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

In Laravel 5.2 I made a folder app/Models.
This is one of my models: app/Models/Pin.php

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Pin extends Model {
    protected $table = 'pins';
}
```

In my composer.json I added to "classmap": app/Models.
Then I runned composer dump-autoload

In my PinController, I have:

```
use App\Models\Pin as Pin;
```

When I do: Pin::all(); it returns a collection.

But when I try: Pin::find(1); I get:

```
Method find not found in class \App\Models\Pin
```

Is their a way I can get all methods from Eloquent?

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing wrong with your approach. It should be working, and it works if I try it on a clean Laravel 5.2.5 install. Maybe some other dependencies are causing side effects for you. Have you tried to isolate the problem on a clean install?

You can find all Eloquent methods in the [API docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html), but keep in mind the Model class has a magic `__call()` method. This is why you won't see a `find()` method directly in the Model class; instead calls to `Model::find()` will be passed to the `Builder::find()`method.

Comment: I tried a clean Laravel 5.2.5 install, and still the same. all() works fine, find(1) not. Is it possible the __call() method doesn't work? I have WAMP Stack 7.0.0-0, can it be the PHP version 7? Or is it something else.

Comment: It turns out that is was null, because the id 1 didn't exist :$ I should have tested it better with findOrFail(); Phpstorm showed find() as marked, that's why I thought the method was not found.